# How to get request parameters in the spring validator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a scenario where I want to get some of the request parameters and validate in the spring validator. could anyone tell me how can I get request Parameteres in spring validator.

Thanks.

```
<c:forEach items="${serviceLocaleList}" var="item" varStatus="count">

                    <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td width="2%" class="formbutton1">
                        <a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggleDivVisibility('myDiv'+'<c:out value="${count.index}"/>',document.getElementById('plusMinusImg'+'<c:out value="${count.index}"/>'))" >
                            <img alt="Show/Hide Filters" src="../images/fold-collapse.gif" id="plusMinusImg<c:out value="${count.index}"/>" />
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="98%" class="formbutton1" valign="middle" align="left">
                        <b><c:out value="${item.language}"></c:out></b>
                    </td></tr>
                    </table>
                    <input type="hidden" name="language<c:out value="${count.index}"/>" value="<c:out value='${item.language}'/>">

                    <div id="myDiv<c:out value="${count.index}"/>" style="display: block">

                        <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0"
                            cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid black;">

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="tabRowLeft" width="20%"><fmt:message key='name' /><font color="#FF0000">*</font></td>
                                        <td class="partner_regn_tr" width="70%">
                                            <input id="Name<c:out value="${count.index}"/>" type="text" size="83" maxlength="25" name="Name<c:out value="${count.index}"/>"  disabled/>
                                            <font color="#FF0000">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
```

My requirement is to get the dynamic localized data and validate. I am actually doing this by calling  the custom validator method in controller.

```
ServiceRegistrationValidator validator = (ServiceRegistrationValidator) getValidator();
//Validate all the request parameters that belongs to Sevrice presentation
validator.validateHttpRequestParameters(request, errors);
```

with the above lines of code, validation is working fine. But I found the user data is getting erased , when there is a validation error. because it is not set in command object.

I tried setting this in comman object after reading it from requestParameter. But spring validator gets called before to call onSubmit. So when ever there is a validation error for other fields which are not localized, the user data entered for localized fields is getting errased.

So, I want to read the requestParameters in validator to resolve the above issue. Could you please let me know if you have some solution.

Comment: provide some code snapshot to understand it better

Comment: I am using spring SimpleFormController for registration page. where I have dynamic data which I am not setting in command object in jsp.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

get the request parameters using @RequestParam tag in Controller

and set the request parameters into command object

and pass the command object to the the validator:

for example:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getRequestParams(@RequestParam("abc") String param1 , @RequestParam("def") String param2, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
   CommandObject commObj = new CommandObject();
   AbcValidator validator = new AbcValidator();
   commanObj.setParam1(param1);
   commanObj.setParam2(param2);
   validator.validate(commandObj);

}
```

It is better u inject commandObj, validator. Try the above example.